# Kisin module for CM elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $E$ be a CM elliptic curve with CM by the field $K$ and assume that $p$ is ramified in $K$ so that $\pi^2 = p \in \mathcal{O}_K$. In particular, then $E$ has supersingular reduction at $p$ and by the arguments in, e.g., this article:
http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/JLseminar/Notes/L17I.pdf
we can compute the Dieudonne module of the corresponding $p$-divisible group.

When $E$ has CM, the prime splitting determines the reduction type. In particular, there are two cases when we have supersingular reduction: when $p$ is inert in $K$ and when $p$ is ramified in $K$. Their Dieudonne modules should be the same, but what about their integral structures, e.g., their Breuil-Kisin modules?

Reference: In the book `Complex multiplication and lifting problems' by Conrad, Chai, and Oort, they construct the Kisin module on an explicit basis when $p$ is inert in the CM field (to construct a Kisin module means for me to choose an explicit $\mathfrak{S}$-basis on which you can write down the Frobenius). In particular, let $\mathcal{G}/\mathcal{O}_L$ be such a $p$-divisible group arising from a CM elliptic curve as above, where $L/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a finite extension and denote by $E(u)$ the Eisenstein polynomial corresponding to $L/L^{\text{ur}}$ where $L^{\text{ur}}\subseteq L$ is the maximal unramified subextension. Then let $\mathfrak{M} = \mathfrak{M}(\mathcal{G})$ be the corresponding Kisin module. In the book, they choose a basis $e_1,e_2$ for $\mathfrak{M}$ where the Frobenius $\phi_{\mathfrak{M}}$ is given by

$$\phi_{\mathfrak{M}}:\left\{\begin{array}{l}e_1\mapsto E(u)e_2\\e_2\mapsto e_1\end{array}\right.$$

What is the analogous presentation when $p$ is ramified?